# Merging two tables with no relationship

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I need to merge two sources, one is an staging table with three rows for data with several attributes, it contains data like `table_id`, `identification`, `date` and more. The other table has three rows and contains a `table_id` and a number.

I want to merge this two tables together to output just three rows, so I want to merge it as is. What I mean is that, the first row that comes from the staging table is going to "add" the number as another attribute from that row.

The tables have no key relationship, so there's no way to link them up. What I did is a merge join using a left outer join on the id's, and it worked, but it's the wrong way to do it, I think it was just because the `table_id`'s are the same.

Here it is what I have done:

[image]

What's the way to go with this? What I'm doing in SSIS is an extraction from a source file, I fill my star schema dimensions with this data and also a staging table. Then I analyze the sentiment of a chat comment that comes from the source file and store it in a dimension table, to finally insert all the info in a fact table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window function to join the tables:

```
select t1.table_id, t1.identification, t1.date, t2.numbercolumn
from (
  select *, row_number() over (order by table_id) rn
  from table1
) t1 left join (
  select *, row_number() over (order by table_id) rn
  from table2
) t2 on t2.rn = t1.rn
```

The 2 tables are sorted by their `id` so the column `rn` in both tables will have values 1,2,3...

Comment: Hi, i already tried out, but the thing is that those sources are from differente databases so i don't know if that would work on SSIS source component.  But it would work with my five star schema dimensions, but i can't chain the five of them, i already tried out but no luck.

Comment: EDIT: Figured it out, SOLVED